# Scripting automated postgres setup

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm scripting a system setup and already have postgres installed.  Here is a test script (run as root) to try and report the working directory in postgres.  Calling `pwd` as postgres gives `/var/lib/postgresql`.  But the test..

```
#!/bin/bash
su - postgres
pwd > /home/me/postgres_report
exit
```

.. fails (obviously) and reports the original working directory.  And afterwards the bash shell is stuck in postgres, suggesting the commands are not being called in right order.  I understand the bash environmental issues here.  I don't have a clue how to do what I need to do, which is automate a postgres process that I can easily do interactively (i.e. step into postgres, execute a command, and exit).  Any pointers?

Comment: why not use fabric which is ideal for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 4):

Use `sudo`.

Use one of:

- Passing a one line command to `psql`

  ```
  sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT ..."`
  ```
- A here document:

  ```
  sudo -u postgres psql <<"__END__"
  SELECT ...;
  SELECT ...;
  __END__
  ```

  (If you want to be able to substitute in shell variables leave out the `"`, e.g. `<<__END__`, and backslash escape `$` signs you don't want to be variables)
- Pass a file to `psql`

  ```
   sudo -u postgres psql -f /path/to/file
  ```

The `sudo -u postgres` is of course only required if you need to become the `postgres` system user to run tasks as the `postgres` database user via `peer` authentication. Otherwise you can use `psql -U username`, a `.pgpass` file, etc.

Comment: Should've mentioned I'm calling the script as root, but I'll check this out

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# run as root
[ "$USER" = "root" ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"

echo "=== $BASH_SOURCE on $(hostname -f) at $(date)" >&2
sudo passwd postgres

echo start the postgres
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start


sudo su - postgres -c \
"psql <<__END__

SELECT 'crate the same user' ;
    CREATE USER $USER ;
    ALTER USER $USER CREATEDB;

SELECT 'grant him the priviledges' ;
    grant all privileges on database postgres to $USER ;
    alter user postgres password 'secret';

SELECT 'AND VERIFY' ;
    select * from information_schema.role_table_grants
    where grantee='""$USER""' ;

SELECT 'INSTALL EXTENSIONS' ;
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\";
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"pgcrypto\";
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"dblink\";

__END__
"

sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status
sudo netstat -tulntp | grep -i postgres
```